# Read a Position based CSV file using Python or pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Python and its library pyspark i need to do some POC where i need to read a CSV file coming from upstream the CSV file which i receive does not have any delimiter it will be a position based file.
We can do this in Oracle control file where we can define position of each column and retrieve the value same i need to do it in pyspark.

I am using Apache Spark to process my Pyspark or python code.

For Ex.

two sample lines from TXT file which could be more in length (there could be empty space as well in the file which needs to be taken into account for defining position of fields)

```
D30056747PRD0091921170811405ACTUAL    ACTUAL    6222020190110001508014
D30056747PRD0091921170811405ACTUAL    ACTUAL    6222020190110001508014
```

below is required values for each column (position could be wrong in my example)

```
col1 = D30056747 [0:9]
col2 = PRD [10:13]
col3 = 0091921170811405 [13:28]
col4 = ACTUAL [29:35]
col5 = ACTUAL [39:45]
col6 = 62220 [49:54]
col7 = 20190110 [54:62]
col8 = 001508014 [52:71]
```

Comment: Your question is sort of unclear

Comment: Please tell me where i am not clear so that i can explain you

Comment: Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looking at it...you mean that you have fixed length columns....since thats the only way it makes sense....so why not import the whole line, remove the white spaces and then you have the proper indexes according to your data structure

Comment: Try this. This may helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940757/parsing-a-text-file-to-split-at-specific-positions-using-pyspark/53941029#53941029

Comment: try to make it delimited first using list with your specified positions, wherein you want to slice the data at specified positions and then can read it into a dataframe.

Comment: you probably need to define your list as cols = [(0,9), (10,13), (13,28),(29,35),(39,45),(49,54),(54,62),(52,71)]

Comment: @vikrant rana: Thanks Man this is what i need just wondering i have 5-6 gb of files would this option will be good enough to do this activity

Comment: @vikrant rana:   Just one thing i need to understand the line in your code 
data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]   how should i read this line

Comment: @mradul.. it's looping to slice each row which is being read and reading tuples positions one by one..  In order to read or process big file you may need to improve a code bit further.. may be read and process the data in chunks or some other way.

Comment: Thanks Vikrant for explaining this just one more question i am getting space's after we slice the value for ACTUAL because it has space in actual lines as well can we do some trimming on these fields to supress these space

Comment: @mradul. well there are couple of ways to do that.. one easiest way is like..  add below statement before you write the data..  data=[elem.strip() for elem in data]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vikrant 
do you also know how to convert CSV to parquet file i ma getting an errror while doing so 
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.parquet  and ValueError: Length of object (79) does not match with length of fields (77)

Comment: @mradul.. Please raise separate question for this. Also there are many info available on SO related to this.

Comment: Thanks i have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a separator when reading a CSV file:

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").csv(file)
```

The separator can be a whitespace o a \t.

Comment: I do not have any delimiter in my file that is the problem